# Isolate images to be modified

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a rich text field (called description) which containing texts and images

I try to isolate all the images to modify the src tag to add elements before and after

example : `<img src="path/to/myimage.jpg" />` should become `<img src="timthumb.php1src=path/to/myimage.jpg&h=50" />`

I succeed when there's just one image in my field, i use this :

```
            $descriptionencodee = utf8_encode($description);
            $parser = xml_parser_create();
            xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $descriptionencodee, $values);
            foreach ($values as $key => $val) {
            if ($val['tag'] == 'IMG') {
               $first_src = $val['attributes']['SRC'];
               break;
            }           


            $string = $description;
            $replacement = '<img src="'timthumb.php?src='. $first_src .'&h=50" />';
//          $replacement = '${1}<br/>';
            $string = preg_replace("/(\<img\b[^>]*>)/", $remplacement, $string);
            echo $string;
```

so it doesn't work when there's more than one image

Comment: The code doesn't look complete - where is the closing bracket of the foreach loop?

Comment: remove break at your if, you find one image and stop loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me in a recent project:

```
<?php
    $content = $your_html_here;

    preg_match_all( '/<img .* \/>/iU', $content, $results );    // Find all <img />
    foreach ( $results[0] as $one_image ){ // Loop through results
        // Replace <img /> with altered <img />
        $content = str_replace( $one_image, str_replace( 'src="', 'src="timthumb.php?h=50&src=', $one_image ), $content );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but do you know how to add something (ie : &h=50) after the img value like this : `src="timthumb.php?src=my_image&h=50`

Comment: That's what this code does :) See the last part of the second-to-last line: `src="timthumb.php?h=50&src=`